# Is there any (eg. security related) reson not to give a webapplication principal full control rights?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

the application i want to deploy on IIS (Windows Server 2012) requires write right within the webapplication directory. The principal (user) of the directory has only read rights right now (seems to be default).

Can giving write rights to this principal (user) be exploited any known way?